# Import csv data laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, csv, import

im using https://github.com/andycrockett/laravel-csv-seeder to import my cvs to laravel. Ok, this work fine. My question is: How hash password of csv?

MY CSV DATA
name,email,password
Steven,st@fake.com,Steven

Here my seeder

```
    class SociosTableSeeder extends CsvSeeder
{
  public function __construct()
      {
          $this->filename = base_path('database\seeds\data\t0.csv');
          $this->table = 'users';

      }

      public function run()
      {
        $this->mapping = [
              0 => 'name',
              1 => 'email',
              2 => 'password',
          ];


          // runs the seeder - alternatively, you could call $this->runSeeder(); for the same result
          parent::run();
      }
}
```

Hashable method dont work for me :C (or I am implementing it badly)
THX ALL!

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs, you should make use of the `hashable` property.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->filename = base_path('database\seeds\data\t0.csv');
    $this->table = 'users';
    $this->hashable = 'password';
}
```

Also take note of your *csv* file, its format might conflict with how the **CSVSeeder** works.